# How do I fix this method to give me 8 individual totals form a 3 dimensional array instead of a

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, return

I grab the array from main, and use those values.

I go to each row and add up each number in each column.

Do i need to make 8 different "Total" Values for this to return different totals for each row?

Or is there a way to call on the method so that it gives the total for a specific row?

```
public static int totalHours(int [][] hoursPerDay)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < hoursPerDay.length; row++)
    {         
        for(int column = 0; column < hoursPerDay[row].length; column++)
        {
            total += hoursPerDay[row][column];
        }
    }
    return total;
}

  String s1 = "Employee#";
  String s2 = "Weekly Hours";
  System.out.format("%-16s%8s", s1, s2 + "\n");
  System.out.print("----------------------------\n");
  for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
  {
     System.out.format("%4d%20d", i, totalHours(hoursPerDay));
     System.out.print("\n");
  }      
Employee#    Weekly Hours
-------------------------
    0             t1
    1             t2
    2             t3
    etc...
```

> I want it to display a table with which employee it is under employee# and the amount of total hours that specific employee worked

Comment: Did you mean 2-dimentional? Your title says 3-dimentional but your question and code is for a 2-dimentional array.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i need to make 8 different "Total" Values for this to return different totals for each row?

If you want to get all totals you need to return an array representing the totals for each row

```
public static int[] totalHours(int [][] hoursPerDay)
{
    int[] totals = new int[hoursPerDay.length];
    for(int row = 0; row < hoursPerDay.length; row++)
    {         
        for(int column = 0; column < hoursPerDay[row].length; column++)
        {
            totals[row] += hoursPerDay[row][column];
        }
    }
    return totals;
}
```

The returned array will contain the totals for each row.

> Or is there a way to call on the method so that it gives the total for a specific row?

There is a way to change the method so that it gives the total for a specific row. You'll need to add a parameter for the row needed and remove the outer `for` loop

```
public static int totalHours(int [][] hoursPerDay, int row)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int column = 0; column < hoursPerDay[row].length; column++)
    {
        total += hoursPerDay[row][column];
    }
    return total;
}
```

For this method you will need to make sure to check that the row requested is not outside of the bounds of the number of available rows just like you would have done in the outer for loop `row < hoursPerDay.length` otherwise there is the potential you will get `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception.

Comment: Im having a problem with the formatting i think. Is there a specific way i need to do this so that it prints && formats each value from the totals array?

Comment: Print and format? I don't understand what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Im using a "System.out.format" line because the output needs to be a certain way. right now i have                                           System.out.format("%4d%20d", i, totalHours(hoursPerDay)); however im getting an error saying IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I  so im guessing that "%20d" is the problem in my code. does that make sense or do you need more?

Comment: I'm on a mobile. Will take a look at this when I get back to my PC. What format are you looking to display the information in. Show a sample output as it is expected to be displayed.

Comment: Im not sure how  can show yo in a comment. since it doesnt allow for new lines. let me try adding the output im looking for in my main question

Comment: i added the desired output in my code at the bottom

Comment: The sample code you have as output is for Java not c#

Comment: Yes i know.I dont know where C# came up. but it is supposed to be in java

Comment: Ok I was under the impression it was for C#. I haven't touched Java in over a decade and not sure if i can be of much more help with the print formatting.

Comment: Any advice is helpful. I honestly dont know where to go and my professor hasn't been responding to my emails.